# How to express $D_4$ group in cycle notations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $D_4$, I express $R_{90}$ (rotation by counter-clockwise $90$ degrees) as $(1 2 34)$ and $H$ (flip around the horizontal axis) as $(14)(23)$.

However, I find that $R_{90}H$ is not equal to $(1234)(14)(23)$.
$R_{90}H=(13)$, but $(1234)(14)(23)=(24)$. Is there anything wrong with my logic?

Comment: In fact $(1234)(14)(23)=(13)$.

Comment: Why? In (23), 3 goes to 2. In (14), there is no 2. In (1234), 2 goes to 3. Hence, 3 goes to 3. It seems like 3 is fixed.

Comment: The first cycle maps, 1  to 2 then  the third cycle maps 2  to 3. It follows that the complete permutation $(1234)(14)(23)$ maps 1 to 3. Other cases can be worked out similarly.

Comment: I read cycles from right to left. That's how the textbook says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the problem is the order you perform your operations. In $S_n$, the notation $\sigma\tau$ means "do $\tau$ first, then do $\sigma$" since multiplication is composition of functions:
$$\sigma\tau(x)=\sigma(\tau(x))$$
Therefore, when you write $R_{90}H$ you should read this as "reflect first, then rotate". If you do it this way, you will get $R_{90}H=(24)$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with notation.  Let $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$ and $I_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  For some $(\sigma\tau)(k)=\sigma(\tau(k))$.  Others calculate $(\sigma\tau)(k)$ as $\tau(\sigma(k))$.